# How to register putty public key on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: ssh, putty, windows-server-2003

So we were trying to transfer files from UNIX server to a Windows server 2003. I currently don't have any visibility on the UNIX server since it is being handled by another team. So in order for the 2 servers to establish connection, they sent us a public key which they said that we need to register on our Windows server 2003 machine.

Can anyone help me? I cant seem to find anything about registering this public key generated by putty on a windows server 2003. there's  no directory to put the public key(like in Linux authorized_keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY is a SSH client, and the public key given to you is specifically for authenticating against a SSH server. So you don't register the key with an OS; you register it with the SSH server.

On Linux, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is read by the OpenSSH service – but **on Windows, you don't *have* a SSH server at all** and will have to install one. Either [Bitvise WinSSHd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) or Cygwin OpenSSH are good options.

Comment: this may be the answer i was looking for. but i tried installing cygwin and ssh/scp doesn't work. why? :(